# cypher neo4j - collect a group of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to get a collection of nodes in my neo4j project

my db try describe connection between users and movies by rating

so i link the users to the movie with link "RATED" that have a rating value(1-5)

in addition i linked the users with themselves with "SIMILARITY" link

now i have groups of users that have liked between them

[the groups of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTo2P.jpg)

i want to see for each group of similarity users:group of movies that liked that movies(liked = rating>=4)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm3y8.jpg)

in this example my result is:Outbreak,Dance With Wolves,Disclosure

Comment: And how do you try to get the result?

Comment: do you use some community algorithm to try and define your groups of similar people ?

Comment: i dont know how to build the query that return me the groups of movies(for each similarity users group)

Comment: how do you get similarity users group ? Just having a relationship with similarity between users is not enough.

Comment: i was created the similarity relationship between the users:
user similar to other user : if they have at least 50% common movies that they liked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have created a direct relationship `SIMILAR` between users, you must run a community detection algorithms, so that it defines different groups of users. You can run it using `apoc.algo` functions using [apoc plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) for neo4j.

```
CALL apoc.algo.community(25,['User'],'community','SIMILAR','BOTH',1,10000)
```

Now that you have defined your user groups with community detection algorithm you can simply query what different groups of users like

```
//You can also set additional filters when matching movies groups liked
MATCH (user:User)-[rel:LIKED]->(m:Movie) where rel.rating > 3.5
RETURN distinct(user.community) as group,collect(m.title) as movies
```

Know that this is a very simple version of how you can implement this. I suggest you check out [this graphgist](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a7c915c8-a3d6-43b9-8127-1836fecc6e2f) and maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMTmG4ClO5I).

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer
but i didn't know how to install the plugin
the neo4j run on windows machine,and all the tutorials are for linux machines

Comment: download the zip version of neo4j, instalation guide here...https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/  ... then just copy the apoc.jar file into neo4j/plugins directory and it will work